# How to embed Ansible facts in a template file?

Tags: jinja2, ansible-2.x

I have a inventory file that looks like this

```
[elk-master-nodes]
10.22.123.123
10.22.234.234
10.22.111.222

[elk-data-nodes]
10.22.111.111
10.22.222.222

[elk-client-nodes]
10.22.111.234
```

I have this in my template file

```
{% if "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}" in groups['elk-master-nodes'] %}
node.master: true
node.data: false
{% elif "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}" in groups['elk-data-nodes'] %}
node.master: false
node.data: true
{% else %}
node.master: false
node.data: false
{% endif %}
```

However, the resulting file ALWAYS has the "else" clause of the if statement, that is, I see this in all my nodes

```
node.master: false
node.data: false
```

I'm guessing I'm not correctly embedding the Ansible fact, ansible_default_ipv4.address, in this case? What is the correct syntax? Removing the "" results in a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Since inside the jinja2 code is basically Python, simply do

```
{% if ansible_default_ipv4.address in groups['elk-master-nodes'] %}
node.master: true
node.data: false
{% elif ansible_default_ipv4.address in groups['elk-data-nodes'] %}
node.master: false
node.data: true
{% else %}
node.master: false
node.data: false
{% endif %}
```